# SQL Server Data types and operators clarification needed

Tags: sql-server

I would like to confirm the following with respect to the basic SQL Queries:

1. The float and real data types cannot be used with the equals and not equals operator in sql. If so then what else operators can i use for these data types.
2. Filtering based on the BLOB and XML columns is not allowed. So shall we disable any search based on these datatypes, also is there any other data type that cannot be filtered from the sql query?

[edit]
3. Also what kind of operators can i use for the timestamp data type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Untrue. You can use them but the "approximate" nature means they could be unreliable.
    Use range queries (BETWEEN etc) or use decimal
2. If you use the max types ([text, image etc are deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)) then you can CAST or SUBSTRING etc as needed to search and filter
   For XML you can search using XQuery
   Note: a binary BLOB that is a word document or such can not be searched in SQL Server
3. Never tried any. timestamp ([deprecated, use rowversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx)) isn't designed to be manipulated
   Unless you mean datetime which as [datetime functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx)